# is there a way to grid an extra button while running your program in tkinter correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an mp3 player app and I want the user to be able to add playlists (which will be buttons in a grid system.
Like so.[image]

However in this state when I'm trying to add a playlist button this happens:
[image]
The top buttons and the button i just added get squeezed off and the scrollbar is stuck (I can't use it)

I've tried refreshing by `self.playlist_frame.update_idletasks()` after running `create_playlists()` but it doesn't seem to change anything

## this is my code so you can test it:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight() - int(self.height / 13)
        self.root.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}')
        self.root.title("Mp3")

        self.c = '#14141D'

        self.playlists_buttons_list = []
        self.playlists = {}
        self.helping_d = {}

        self.main = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.playlists_tab = tk.Frame(self.main)
        self.playlist_menu_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_tab, bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.playlists_tab, bg=self.c)
        self.playlist_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_canvas, bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.playlists_tab, orient='vertical',
                                                 command=self.playlists_canvas.yview)
        self.add_playlist_win = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.add_playlists_button = tk.Button(self.playlist_frame)
        self.default_img = Image.open('images/default.png').resize((75, 72))
        self.default_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.default_img)
        self.add_img = Image.open('images/add.png').resize((50, 50))
        self.add_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.add_img)
        self.widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def widgets(self):
        self.playlists_tab.place(height=self.height, width=self.width, x=0, y=0)
        self.main.add(self.playlists_tab, text="Playlists")
        self.main.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        self.playlist_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_canvas, bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.playlist_frame, anchor='center')
        self.playlists_canvas.config(bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_canvas.place(height=int(self.height / 1.428), width=self.width, x=0, y=int(self.height / 9))
        self.add_playlists_button = tk.Button(self.playlists_canvas, image=self.add_img, bg=self.c, bd=0,
                                              command=self.add_playlists)
        self.add_playlists_button.place(x=1284, y=75)
        self.playlists_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.playlists_canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.playlists_scrollbar.set)
        self.playlists_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.playlists_canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=self.playlists_canvas.bbox('all')))

        if os.path.getsize('playlistsnames.txt') != 0:
            lines = open('playlistsnames.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()
            for i in lines:
                self.playlists[i] = []

        self.create_playlists()

    def create_playlists(self):
        self.playlists_buttons_list = []

        for i in range(len(self.playlists.keys())):
            self.playlists_buttons_list.append(tk.Button(self.playlist_frame, bg=self.c,
                                                         text=' ' + list(self.playlists.keys())[i].split('!')[0],
                                                         fg='white', image=self.default_img, height=280, width=300))
            row = 0
            column = 0
            for i in self.playlists_buttons_list:
                if column > 3:
                    row += 1
                    column = 0
                if column > 7:
                    row += 1
                    column = 0
                i.grid(row=row, column=column)
                column += 1

    def get_name(self):
        self.name_of_plst = self.plst_entry.get()
        self.playlists[self.name_of_plst] = []
        self.create_playlists()

        with open('playlistsnames.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as names_file:
            names_file.write(self.name_of_plst + '!\n')

    def add_playlists(self):
        self.add_playlist_win = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.name_label = tk.Label(self.add_playlist_win, text='Name:', bg=self.c, fg='pink').pack()
        self.plst_entry = tk.Entry(self.add_playlist_win)
        self.plst_entry.pack()
        self.confirm_btn = tk.Button(self.add_playlist_win, text='Confirm', bg=self.c, fg='pink',
                                     command=self.get_name).pack()
        self.add_playlist_win.mainloop()


MyApp()
```

I should also mention that because I store the playlist names in a file called playlistnames.txt when I rerun the program I can see all the playlist buttons plus the one I created before and things work just fine.
So what I want is making the grid update and work **while** running the app **without** having to rerun the app of course

My playlistsnames.txt file has this format: 
rock! 
metal! 
chill! 
rap! 
jazz! 
blues! 
hard rock! 
trap!

Any suggestions would be helpful!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should bind `<Configure>` on `self.playlist_frame` instead of `self.playlists_canvas`.

Comment: @acw1668 Oh god! finally this made it work properly. Thanks so much! Is there a way to bind mousewheel as well (I have a function ready but how can I bind it as well)